# Why does background-position-y not work on safari with full screen background + overlay?

Tags: html, css, safari

```
<div class=" backgroundimage"> </div>
```

```
.backgroundimage {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(191,0,0,1),rgba(191,0,0,1)),url(image) no-repeat center center;
    background-position-y: 250px !important;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

This is the code that I am using. From some research, I found that in order to add a color overlay on an image is to use a gradient with the same color throughout. 
This works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome with the multiply blend mode, however on Safari it just display the solid color. If I remove the background-position-y then Safari will display it correctly with the multiply blend mode.

I did notice that the background-position-y does work without the gradient overlay just not both at the same time.

Does any one have any ideas why the position breaks this on safari?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a "full screen background"? It would be helpful if you would convert your code into a working snippet to illustrate your issue (and include a working URL for your image, even if it's just a placeholder like http://placekitten.com/200/300).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-image` and use `:before` for the gradient

Here's an example:

```
 <div class="backgroundimage"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
   body , html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.backgroundimage{
    position: relative;
    background: url('img') no-repeat center center; 
    background-position-y: 250px !important;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.backgroundimage:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(191,0,0,1),rgba(191,0,0,1)); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(191,0,0,1),rgba(191,0,0,1));/* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(191,0,0,1),rgba(191,0,0,1)); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    opacity: .6; 
}
```